# How can I solve the large scale convex optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I have a large scale convex optimization problem as the following shows.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^K}{\text{minimize}} & -\alpha^T[\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{Ax}]\\ 
\text{subject to} & \mathbf{Bx}\le \mathbf{b}\\ & (\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{Px})\odot(\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{Px})-\mathbf{Qx}\le \mathbf{d}\end{array}$$

where $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}^K$, $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product and $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{P}, \mathbf{Q} \in {\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times K}$.

I would like to solve it via using barrier function based interior point method and proximity operator.

What I have tried...

$$\text{minimize}  -\alpha^T[\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{Ax}] - \mu[\sum_\limits{i=1}^{M}\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{b}_i - \mathbf{B}_{i,:}x) + \sum_\limits{i=1}^K\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{d}_i-(1+\mathbf{P}_{i,:}\mathbf{x})^2-\mathbf{Q}_{i,:}\mathbf{x})] $$

If I set $$F(\mathbf{x})=-\alpha^T[\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{Ax}]- \mu\sum_\limits{i=1}^K\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{d}_i-(1+\mathbf{P}_{i,:}\mathbf{x})^2-\mathbf{Q}_{i,:}\mathbf{x})$$ and $$G(\mathbf{x})=-\mu\sum_\limits{i=1}^{M}\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{b}_i - \mathbf{B}_{i,:}\mathbf{x}).$$

Firstly, do a forward step for $F(\mathbf{x})$, i.e.,
$$\mathbf{x}_{k+1} = \mathrm{prox}_{\mu_k\gamma_kG}(\mathbf{x}_k-\gamma_k\nabla_1F(\mathbf{x}_k))$$

As we know, a proximal operator for function $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$ is formulated as
$$\mathrm{prox}_f(\mathbf{x}) = arg\min_\limits{\mathbf{u}}\frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u}||^2+\gamma f(\mathbf{u})$$

so
$$\mathbf{x}_{k+1} = \mathrm{prox}_{\mu_k\gamma_kG}(\mathbf{x}_k-\gamma_k\nabla_1F(\mathbf{x}_k)) \\
= arg\min_\limits{\mathbf{u}}\frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{x}_k-\gamma_k\nabla_1F(\mathbf{x}_k)||^2 -\mu_k\sum_\limits{i=1}^{M}\mathrm{ln}(\mathbf{b}_i - \mathbf{B}_{i,:}\mathbf{u}) $$

There is a solution associated above problem's subproblem
[image]

**while my question is that the solution can't be applied to the sum of several affine constraints. So what should I do?**

Comment: When using a vector of ones, use something like `\Bbb 1` to distinguish it from $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll correct it.

Comment: We can minimize $\sum_{i\in I} f_i(x)$ using only the individual proxes $\textrm{prox}_{f_i}$ via applying Douglas-Rachford on the reformulation *minimize* $ P(x) + Q(x)$, where $x=(x_1,...,x_m)$ and $P(x)=f_1(x_1)+...+f_m(x_m)$ and $Q$ is the $0$-$\infty$ indicator function of the subspace $\{(x_1,...,x_m)\,|\,x_1=...=x_m\}$. This way, $\textrm{prox}_P$ is the componentwise application of the $\textrm{prox}_{f_i}$'s, and $\textrm{prox}_Q$ just replaces with the average in every component. This will increase your storage requirements though.